# Cover flow doesn't update after I delete a file

Tags: macos

I have a folder with images. I'm viewing it in cover flow mode. After I delete an item, the preview stays the same and no longer reflects the currently highlighted item. Is this a bug, is there a quick way to force a refresh?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug, at least in Mavericks. I've filed a bug report with Apple. You can refresh the coverflow view by changing the sort order, e.g. change from ascending name to descending and back again.